# Query in a loop how to get result array in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am trying to fetch result of a query that is in a loop but i cant get all the records returned by query that is in the loop please guide me.

```
  $qry = '';
    $qry = "SELECT    
            `user_id`  FROM 
            `view_property_user_lab`";
    $qry .= " WHERE property_id = '" . $propId . "'";
    $result = $this->db->query($qry);
    $result_count = $result->result_array();
    foreach ($result_count as $row)
    {
        $user_name_qry = "SELECT
                                 `name`
                                    FROM USER
                                    WHERE user_id =  '" . $row['user_id'] . "'";
                                   $user_name_result = $this->db->query($user_name_qry);
    }

    $result_count_user = $user_name_result->result_array();
    print_r($result_count_user);
```

This is the dump of array

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => abc) )
```

Comment: queries in a loop is very bad idea, especially since your loop will grow with each new user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're using a foreach loop, but everytime you **overwrite** the same variable (`$user_name_result`) and you use only the last one assigned to get the data from the result resource (since you're calling that *outside* the loop!).

But all in all, as tersko said in the comments, doing queries in loops isn't a good thing (hitting your db the more your users increase).

You can simplify everything with a JOINed query (just guessing your table schema here, though):

```
$sql = "SELECT u.name FROM view_property_user_lab AS v JOIN user AS u ON u.user_id = v.user_id WHERE v.property_id = ?";
$query = $this->db->query($sql,array($propID));

print_r($query->result_array());
```